# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I have this project running on Laravel 5.8 and Database on Mysql using XAMPP server.

This is my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This is my `config/database.php` file:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

and also created a Database in Xampp named `homestead`.

this error is showing: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from` users`where`email `= test@gmail.com`

Comment: try to use "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" (after having check the password is correct)

Comment: @GiacomoM I have tried this also still showing me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide db_name, mysql user_name and password in your .env file.
for xampp default username is 'root' and no password.
so update your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=matkagu_satta
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but still showing me the same error.

Comment: do you have to provide a user name and password to login to your phpmyadmin ? if yes give that username and password in .env

Comment: No, That is not the case.I m able to see my database without login.

Comment: then login to phpmyadmin. open 'mysql' database, go to user table, you can see users available in there. check if your 'root' user have password

Comment: The actual error is `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'matkagu_satta'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = matkaguru@gmail.com limit 1`.

Comment: check 'matkagu_satta' user have all the permission in user table of mysql db

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: open phpmyadmin in there you will have a database named 'mysql' in that db you will have a table named 'user'. check in this table

Comment: Yes,'matkagu_satta' have all the user permissions

Comment: does 'matkagu_satta' have password ? if no then copy the env from answer again. i have updated it

Comment: No,  'matkagu_satta' don't have password

Comment: then update your env with the code in the answer (i have updated the answer)

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: clear all cache

Comment: Already did. `php artisan config:clear`  `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: So sorry, I was changing to `.examplefile`. now that I changed to `.env` it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Good. all the best with your project mate...

Comment: Can you share your GitHub profile?

Comment: https://github.com/yadusivadas